# Jhipster registry 3.2.4 : Getting empty page

Tags: jhipster-registry

I have imported jhipster Registry version 3.2.4, deploy correctly, open `localhost:8761` I get a empty page, there is no error information. I did `yarn start` also but I am getting the error

> 'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command

[image: screen shot of console]

Comment: You have to install  'webpack-dev-server' probably.

Comment: yeah I did that using " yarn add --dev webpack webpack-dev-server " command. I am getting "stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python".  @David

Comment: Then you've to add the PATH to the python-bin-directory to your windows-PATH-variable

Comment: How-to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28778358/1019850

Comment: thanks@David it worked